# DB2 to Snowflake Migration - SQL: Deriving a result table using 'values' clause

Tags: db2, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are migrating off DB2 to Snowflake, and we have run into an issue with a lack of scope when using the 'values' clause.  DB2 scope extends to all tables within the select query; while Snowflake is limited to that within the clause:

Valid in DB2:

```
select * from
t_1
join

table (values
(t_1.c1, ‘foo’)
,(t_1.c1, ‘bar’)
) as t_2 (c1, c2)

on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
```

Not valid in Snowflake (slightly different syntax - remove 'table'):

```
select * from
t_1
join

(values
(t_1.c1, ‘foo’)
,(t_1.c1, ‘bar’)
) as t_2 (c1, c2)

on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
```

This throws an error saying "*...t_1 is undefined*".

**Does anyone know of an equivalent capability in Snowflake?**

For some context:  This construct sits behind a well embedded process for our business, and to rework it would mean significant investment.

It forms the basis for a dynamic ETL query which is passed into an ADF pipeline.  There is a frontend which deploys components into this query - this deployable piece needs to be kept as simple as possible.  It is the equivalent to the "(t_1.c1, ‘foo’)" line, so ideally any solution would keep this piece the same.

EDIT:

For some additional context...

In the example above, we have a placeholder which identifies the insert point of newly deployed items from the front end, like this:

```
select * from
t_1
join

table (values
(t_1.c1, ‘foo’)
,(t_1.c1, ‘bar’)
/*client_X_placeholder*/
) as t_2 (c1, c2)

on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2

union

select * from
t_1
join

table (values
(t_1.c1, ‘foo’)
,(t_1.c1, ‘bar’)
,(t_1.c2, 'barfoo')
/*client_Y_placeholder*/
) as t_2 (c1, c2)

on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
```

We are pulling a series of metrics associated with clients, where the label is t_2.c2 and the result is t2.c1.  This is still highly simplified relative to the real world.  We need a simple way to update the placeholder with a new metric and its calculation - t2.c1 may be wrapped in a pile of functions and/or reside inside case statements, etc.

Comment: is the `t_1.c1` part dynamic? I Assume so, but that seems rather not Snowflakes valid.

Comment: Not dynamic, no.  But as per the edit, new rows may be inserted to the table.

Comment: SimeonPilgrim, Lennart - Thanks both for your efforts - adding the lateral and "select * from" in has worked a treat.  I wish there was a way I could give you both credit for this...

Comment: upvotes on answers works quite well (as a second place to answer tickets)

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim  Hmm - well, I thought this was going to work... but I spoke too soon.  It seems that with Snowflake anything inside the values clause needs to be evaluated at compile time - so while the scope solution has been found, I still can't actually select anything from that table!

Comment: Heh - It's my first post, so don't have the reputation to upvote, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lennart deserve this one, his code is so close

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
)
select *
from t_1
join lateral (values 
    (t_1.c1, 'foo'),
    (t_1.c1, 'bar')
    )  as t_2(c1,c2)
    on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2;
```

but that causes an internal error:

> 000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:
> Processing aborted due to error 300002:4143448929; incident 4919401.

But if you put a `SELECT * FROM` in there:

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
)
select *
from t_1
join lateral (select * from values 
    (t_1.c1, 'foo'),
    (t_1.c1, 'bar')
    ) as t_2(c1,c2)  
    on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2;
```

it works:

| C1 | C5 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | bar | a | bar |

Lenart's try more brackets works also:

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
)
select *
from t_1
join lateral (
    select * from (
        values 
        (t_1.c1, 'foo'),
        (t_1.c1, 'bar')
    )
) as t_2(c1,c2)  
    on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2;
```

Comment: That's an interesting limitation. Is it possible to: `select * from ( values (1),(2) ) t` ?

Comment: @Lennart that works..

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether this works in snowflake, but SQL requires you to declare t_2 as LATERAL if you want to reference t_1 inside of it. Db2 uses tables as a synonym for lateral (which works as well). So you could try:

```
select * 
from t_1
join LATERAL (
    values (t_1.c1, ‘foo’)
         , (t_1.c1, ‘bar’)
    ) as t_2 (c1, c2)
  on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
```

Lateral was introduced in SQL99 and is supported by many DBMS including Db2.

In Db2, TABLE is typically used when selecting from a function returning a table:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ( myfun() )
```

which is somewhat similar so I guess that is why TABLE can act as a synonym for LATERAL (just guessing).

I did some googling and LATERAL is described in the docs for snowflake: [join-lateral](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html)

EDIT:

Apparently, there is a limitation when it comes to joining the values clause in the derived table. The answer by [Simeon Pilgrim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43992/simeon-pilgrim) contains a fix for this

Answer (score 0):

hmm, that string is almost correlated subquery/join with values:

The first thought I have is:

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
)
select t_1.*, t_1.c1 as c1, t_2.c2 
from t_1
join values ('foo'),
  ('bar') as t_2(c2)
    on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
;
```

but the part you wanting would look like (if it works):

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
)
select t_1.*, t_1.c1 as c1, t_2.c2 
from t_1
join values 
    (t_1.c1, 'foo'),
    (t_1.c1, 'bar')
        as t_2(c1,c2)
    on t_1.c5 = t_2.c2
;
```

but it doesn't work.... more thinking required.

So IF that block comes in as

```
(t_1.c1, 'foo'),
(t_1.c1, 'bar')
```

then you can mash it into block with `%%stuff%%`

and then rip it apart and hoop jump..

```
WITH t_1 (c1, c5) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'bar'
), magic as (         
    SELECT 
       split(t.value, ',') as p
       ,trim(get(p,0),'"') as p0
       ,trim(get(p,1),' \'")') as p1
    
    FROM table(split_to_table($$(t_1.c1, 'foo'),
                              (t_1.c1, 'bar')$$,'(')) as t
    WHERE t.value <> ''
), hoop_jumping(c1, c2) as (
    SELECT 
        case p0
               WHEN 't_1.c1' then t_1.c1
               WHEN 't_1.c5' then t_1.c5
        end,
        p1
    FROM magic, t_1
)
SELECT t.*, h.*
FROM t_1 as t
JOIN hoop_jumping as h
   ON t.c5 = h.c2
```

and as long as you are will to cover all the bases of what was selected:

| C1 | C5 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | bar | a | bar |

but I suspect it makes more sense to inject that block into a snowflake scripting block, and use it as injected code.

Comment: Thanks Simeon - appreciate your response, but unfortunately the construct is too complex for the front end to easily update with new components.  I'll add some more context to the question :)

Comment: @Jase250 I though you said the `(t_1.c1, 'foo'),(t_1.c1, 'bar')` was the part written by the front end. If more is written by the front end, then this plan will not work.

Comment: @Jase250 can you update the question to be very explicit about the "unchangeable part"

Comment: I've added some more context to the question.  Some clients have hundreds of metrics, and we have hundreds of clients, so the complex solution would grow too big too quickly.   I'm having a re-look at your simpler solution as I may have misunderstood how it works - here's hoping, because you would have solved a major roadblock for us if so!